# Extend the url with a file extension using an htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess file where my urls are overwritten.
This works great.

Now I want the ending ".html" to be inserted automatically at all urls.
If there is "/" at the end, this should be removed.

Here is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: OK. Sounds like a plan. And what is your question? Where did you struggle?

Comment: when I call the url "example.com/test1/test2" this url is also displayed. But it should be "example.com/test1/test2.html"

Comment: Sure, that is what you wrote. Why ever you want that. So you want to implement an additional redirection rule. Which is why I asked what detail you struggle with. So that we can help.

Comment: Please understand how this place works: we are not a free coding service. We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help you if you struggle, but you are expected to be the active part. You need to implement that rule, so you should do it. You will find many examples for that here or on google. And definitely the documentation of the apache rewrite module will help you to understand: it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples. So go, start yourself and test your rule(s). Then, if you struggle with a detail you cannot solve, then is the time to ask about that here.